# Firebase Firestore not showing documents created by my flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was able to configure the Firestore database in Firebase with my flutter app and also create and read documents from my collection but when I go to Firestore console I don't see the created data, also when I creat data manually I am unable to see it in my application.

I am using the test mode which means any user can read or write.

I hope someone can help me with this puzzle.
Thanks!!!

Comment: We need to see your code in order to help debug. Any errors, logs etc would help too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the device/emulator that you are running on is not connected to the internet, or at least not to the Firestore servers. In that case, the client writes all local changes into a local database, waiting to send them to the server when it gets a connection. So the local app will work, but won't be able to synchronize its local cache with the database servers.

You might want to check the connection on your device, and any proxies that might exist between your app and the Firestore servers.

Comment: Our engineers take pride in that, as it seems Firestore's offline mode works quite well for you then. :)

Comment: Yes, it does, and as soon as I fixed the internet connection in the emulator all data went to firebase :)

Comment: Yup. One of my favorite demos with Firebase is to kill wifi, and keep demoing, and then watch it reconcile everything once you reconnect. https://youtu.be/xAsvwy1-oxE?t=855 :)

Comment: I have the same problem but I am connected to the internet for sure, since I play an online quiz on that app. I am using react-native-firebase. Not sure what may cause this. Does anyone know? Thanks!

Comment: If you're certain you're online, it is not the same problem as this developer had. I recommend posting a new question, with its own [minimal complete reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and enough information for us to help.